# Where to find photos

Tags: python, word-cloud

I use pycharm and I run the code from github.
where can I get the word-cloud image?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Minimal Example
===============
Generating a square wordcloud from the US constitution using default arguments.
"""

import os

from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud

# get data directory (using getcwd() is needed to support running example in generated IPython notebook)
d = path.dirname(__file__) if "__file__" in locals() else os.getcwd()

# Read the whole text.
text = open(path.join(d, 'crawling.xlsx')).read()  #I used my text. Only here was corrected.

# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")

# lower max_font_size
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

# The pil way (if you don't have matplotlib)
image = wordcloud.to_image()
image.show()
```

And I wonder if separate tokenization or string cleansing is required when using the word cloud library.

Answer (score 0):

Add this one line to the end to save the image:

```
image.save("constitution.png")
```

See [Pillow reference for Image.save](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save).